Creating internal S3 methods in package development
I want to use S3 dispatch for an internal function. However, when I create something like
myfun <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("myfun")
}

myfun.someclass <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}

roxygen complains: "S3 method myfun.someclass needs @export or @exportS3method tag."
I figured out that when I rename my function to .myfun(), all is fine.
Is that the rule? You can't have internal S3 methods unless you prepend the function name with a .? I couldn't find any documentation related to that, so I'm a bit confused: Are internal S3 methods generally discouraged in packages and I just found a hack, or is that a fine thing to do?

Noting an additional oddity: when I prepend the function with a ., I can't get roxygen to accept #' @rdname .myfun in the package documentation.

For S3 methods, @export doesn't actually export the method, but instead registers it. The right way to handle this is to register the S3 methods by adding the @export tag, but not then simply not export the generic function.
Roxygen complains when you don't register an S3 method and from R 3.5 onwards all S3 methods should be registered.

More precisely, @export causes Roxygen to output the code to register the method.  I have no idea why they chose to use that keyword; R makes a clear distinction between registering methods and exporting functions.
